# Como abrir un archivo excel desde un script de sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, archivo, macros

Desde un script de sql server necesito abrir un archivo excel.xlsm

Tengo un stored procedure que genera varios `txt` y paralelamente tengo una excel con una macro que se activa al abrir ese excel y usa los datos del txt del SP.

Mi intención es automatizar todo el proceso, para eso necesito que el SP ejecute/ abra el excel.

Actualmente obtengo el error:

> exec master..xp_cmdshell '\servidor\carpeta\excel.xlsm', no_output

Comment: Que bien. Qué has intentado?

Comment: Hola. intenté lo siguiente pero se me cuelga el script:   exec master..xp_cmdshell '\\servidor\carpeta\excel.xlsm', no_output

Comment: Qué es **exactamente** lo que intentas lograr? Qué significa para ti "**abrir**" un archivo excel? Lo que quiere es insertar la información de excel en una tabla?

Comment: tengo un stored procedure que genera varios txt y paralelamente tengo una excel con una macro que se activa al abrir ese excel y usa los datos del txt del SP, mi intensión es automatizar todo el proceso, para eso necesito que el SP ejecute/ abra el excel.

Comment: @martin tal vez quieras agregar el cdigo del sp, segun tengo entendido deberias de estar usando transact sql.